# Trocar um caractere dentro de uma string em c

Tags: c

Por que essa substituição de um caractere dentro de uma string não esta funcionando?

```
int main(){
    char *armazena = "XXX", letra = 'a';
    letra = armazena[2];
    *(armazena+1) = 'a';
    printf("%c", armazena[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *armazena = "XXX"` cria uma string *readonly* (não pode ser modificada), daí o erro. Troque por `char armazena[] = "XXX"`. Veja mais em https://stackoverflow.com/q/7564033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como já dito nos comentários, strings declaradas como `char *string = ""` não podem ser modificadas. Mas por que?

A razão dela não poder ser modificada, é porque você criou um *ponteiro* que referencia uma *string* estática, ou seja, foi criada em tempo de compilação. Essa string será armazenada nos binários do seu programa compilado, e não no contexto da sua função (ou da *pilha de memória*).

Não apenas isso, mas o seu programa é otimizado para que todas as strings estáticas idênticas apontem para o mesmo endereço de memória.

Por exemplo, no seguinte código:

```
char *str1 = "XXX";
char *str2 = "XXX";
```

`str1` e `str2` não são apenas strings idênticas, elas são exatamente a mesma string no endereço de memória, o que significa que se você modificar `str1`, estaria modificando `str2`.

Isso abre a possibilidade de diversos problemas com strings sendo declaradas em arquivos diferentes sendo acidentalmente modificadas. Por tal razão o compilador irá tentar te impedir de modificar tais strings, e você também deveria evitar faze-lo, mesmo que consiga burlar a verificação.

---

**Como criar uma string mutável**

Qualquer string não-estática pode ser modificada, seja ela declarada na pilha de memória:

```
char str[] = "XXX";
str[0] = 'Z';

printf("%s", str);
```

Ou no [heap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap):

```
char *str = malloc(4); // reservo espaço para 4 caracteres no heap
strcpy(str, "XXX"); // copio o conteúdo da string estática para o heap
str[0] = 'Z';

printf("%s", str);
free(str);
```

Comment: E qual seria a maneira de alterar um caractere de uma string que e passada por um vetor dentro de uma funcao?

Comment: @HigorLuiz, veja se a edição te ajuda.